# How to print one word at a time on one line?

Tags: python, time, sys

I want to write code which allows me to print a word out and then it disappears and the next word prints. For example, if I have "Hello World!," the program should print "Hello" then the word disappears and then "World!" prints and then disappears. I should be able to change the speed of the printing words as well. Currently I was able to figure out how to print characters at a certain speed, but how do I print words one by one?

```
import time
import sys

def print_char(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % c )
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)

print_char("hello world")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

data = "this is a sentence with some words".split()

max_len=max([len(w) for w in data])
pad = " "*max_len
for w in data:
    sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % pad)
    sys.stdout.write("%s\r" % w)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.4)

print
```

Example, just for the fun of it

[image]

Comment: I run this code through Python shell and I am not getting the same result as the gif file.

Comment: which python version? which os (in the gif I use sleep 0.4 just to have a clean separation of the words)

Comment: python 3.3.2 i have windows 8

Comment: Tested using python 3.3.0 (on linux) and it works. Updated the code to my exact version (used in gif). Hope it helps...

Comment: I am using python 3.3.2 shell and I am still getting the same problem

Comment: well, what do you get? Please copy the exact output and place it, either update your post or put it on pastebin.

Comment: >>> 
        
this
        
is
        
a
        
sentence
        
with
        
some
        
words

>>> it just prints the word one by one, but the previous words are not deleting

Comment: Probably an issue with the python-shell. Execute the code from the command-prompt. Start the windows-shell (cmd) and do `python c:\path\to\file\file.py`

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19188881/297323 apparently `\r` and `\b` have som issues in IDLE.

Comment: I did it in the cmd, and it works perfectly. Do you have any suggestions for shell?

Comment: Glad you got it to work! See my link, no support for those characters. What you can do is to use curses instead. Read more in http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/curses.html to see what you can use on windows

Answer (score 0):

If `words` is a list of strings:

```
def print_char(words):
    for s in words:
        for c in s:
            sys.stdout.write('%s' %c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        # erase the word
        sys.stdout.write('\b'*len(s))  # backspace the cursor
        sys.stdout.write(' '*len(s))  # overwrite with spaces
        sys.stdout.write('\b'*len(s))  # backspace again, to write the next word
```

Comment: howabout using `sys.stdout.write("%s\r"% s)` and prior to that the same with witespace the maximum length of strings in word?

Comment: When I run this code, it adds a space between all the characters. It is not deleting the previous words. Is there at least a way for me to print the words one by one?

Comment: I just tested this on python3.3 and it works per the description in your OP. Do you want to print each word in a separate line, or do you want to erase each word and overwrite it with the next one? Also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: I want to erase the word and replace it with the next word. I am using python 3.3

Comment: @edboysega321: then this code should work. It works on my py3.3

Comment: I am actually using python 3.3.2 shell. Should I use another program?

Comment: >>> print_char("words words words words words words words")
w o r d s   w o r d s   w o r d s   w o r d s   w o r d s   w o r d s   w o r d s This is what I'm getting

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19188881/297323 apparently \r and \b have som issues in idle. Use a different shell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer to this question:

[remove last STDOUT line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python)

You can do something like this:

```
import time
import sys

CURSER_UP_ONE = '\x1b[1A'
ERASE_LINE = '\x1b[2K'

def delay_print(sentence, pause_between_words):
    for s in sentence.split(" "):
        sys.stdout.write( '%s' % s)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(pause_between_words)
        print(ERASE_LINE + CURSER_UP_ONE)

delay_print("Hello World!", 0.5)
```

This code will print a word at a time in my terminal, remove the last word and print the next. The last word will be deleted just before termination. Is this how you want it to work? Else let me know.

EDIT: Noticed that you also wanted to have a delay between each character print. Have updated my code accordingly.

EDIT: Based on your comment I removed char by char printing.

Comment: I want to print out one word, then the word erases, and the next word prints. I don't want to print a character one by one

Comment: I have updated my code accordingly to reflect this. How does it look now?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what youre looking for, and it might not be as fast as some of the other answers, but something that you can do is this:

```
import time, os

text = "This is a long sentence that has a lot of words in it.".split()

for i in range(len(text)):
    os.system("clear")
    print(text[i])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    os.system("clear")
```

Where text is the text you want to type, and time.sleep(XXX) is the time between words shown.