# How do I print one word at a time in python shell?

Tags: python, shell, python-curses

I already have code for performing this task, but I can only perform this in the command prompt. The number you put into the function is words per minute, so if you input 60, you will get 60 wpm, or one word per second.

```
import sys
import time

data = "is sentence with some words this is a some. words this is a sentence with some words".split()


def inputwordsperminute(x):


    max_len=max([len(w) for w in data])
    pad = " "*max_len
    for w in data:
        sys.stdout.write('%s\r' % pad)
        sys.stdout.write("%s\r" % w)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep((60.0/x))

print

inputwordsperminute(200)
```

I was told that I have to import curses in order to get this working in shell. How do I do that? Will I need to write something completely different?

Comment: Do you want to have only one word visible at once? Or all words in a row?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me in the python shell (running python with no arguments) and in ipython. What do you see when *you* try it?

Comment: only one word visible at once. The code works in cmd

Comment: By 'python shell', do you mean the Python REPL (when you run python without parameters)? IPython? IDLE? It works in REPL for me.

Comment: "        
is
        
sentence
        
with
        
some
        
words
        
this
        
is
        
a
        
some.
        
words
        
this
        
is
        
a
        
sentence
        
with
        
some
        
words

>>> " I am using Shell 3.3.2. IDLE specifically

Comment: What is "Shell 3.2.2", where have you got it and how do you start it? If it's just Python 3.2.2, it works for me, too (in 3.2.3). I run under Linux, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a backspace in Python 3.3.2 Shell using Idle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187759/implementing-a-backspace-in-python-3-3-2-shell-using-idle)

Comment: In any case, `curses` only work under Unix-like OSes (and OS/2), not under Windows.

Comment: I read that page, but how can I do it in IDLE?

Comment: You can't. That functionality is not available in IDLE. Neither curses, nor `'\r'`, nor ANSI escape sequences work in IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

I"m not sure I'm clear on what the question is, but just changing your \r's to \n's and eliminating the padding may give something usable without curses:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

import sys
import time

data = "is sentence with some words this is a some. words this is a sentence with some words".split()

def inputwordsperminute(x):
    #max_len=max([len(w) for w in data])
    #pad = " "*max_len
    for w in data:
        #sys.stdout.write('%s\n' % pad)
        sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % w)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep((60.0/x))

print

inputwordsperminute(200)
```

Comment: He wants the `\r` in order to produce an overstrike effect.

Comment: Add 200 wpm?  That's too fast for \r.