# Print lines on top of each other in python 2.7

Tags: python, function, printing, output

I want to print such that the new print object replaces the old printed object in the same line. Here is what I do:

```
for i in range(0,10000): 
     print "\r", i,
```

However the result that this gives me is this:

```
9999 1415
```

I expect to only see 9999. I do not know why it prints out 1415.

There are people who have given answers on this topic before but they have been focused on python 3.x. I have python 2.7 with Canopy.

Comment: Do you run it from IDLE? The code above works great if executed from shell. `\b` and `\r` does not work from within idle. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187759/implementing-a-backspace-in-python-3-3-2-shell-using-idle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure? Here is my output in Python 2.7. It works fine

```
 Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for i in range(0,10000): 
...      print "\r", i,
... 
9999 
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDLE console **doesn't support**  `\r` to overwrite characters that have been printed. Such techniques will work if you run python from shell.

Same case with `\b` too. There is nothing wrong in your program.